# Axiom in Foundations, Extensionality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms, foundations

In my Foundations of Mathematics Textbook I encountered the following problem.

The book states that for the domain of discourse $D = \{a,b,c\}$ and binary relation defined as $E = \{(a,b),\, (a,c)\}$  the [extensionality axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) is violated. What I understand this axiom to mean is that if two sets have the same elements than they are equal, so why is this true?

Edit: I believe I am confused by this notation does {a,b} mean an element obtained from a binary relation with a and b?

Comment: Well, $b$ and $c$ have the same elements but are not equal...

Comment: $\{a,b\}$ just means a set with elements a, b.

Comment: You mean "binary relation", not "binary operation"?

Comment: @SunghyukPark ok that makes sense, my mistake, but what does it mean in relation to extensionality. The sets {a,b} and {a,c} are not equal?

Comment: What textbook is it? The author please

Comment: @ magma https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m771-10/kunen770.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What extensionality *actually* says is that if $x$ and $y$ are such that $z\mathbin{E} x\Leftrightarrow z\mathbin{E} y$ for all $z$, then $x=y$.  In your example it is true that $z\mathbin{E} b\Leftrightarrow z\mathbin{E} c$ for all $z\in D$ (since the only $z$ such that $z\mathbin{E} b$ is $z=a$ and similarly for $c$).  Since $b\neq c$, this means extensionality fails.

Extensionality only says "if two sets have the same elements than they are equal" if you think of the relation $E$ as being the "element" relation $\in$ between sets.  That is, if you pretended $b$ and $c$ were sets, and their elements were exactly those $z$ such that $z\mathbin{E} b$ and $z\mathbin{E} c$, then $b$ and $c$ would have exactly the same elements (namely, just $a$).